# rosserial_client does not include make_library.py

Tags: ros, github, rosserial-client, ros-groovy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon partners.

I've just installed this morning Rasbpian/Groovy on a second raspberry of mine.

When I follow the instructions to get "rosserial" on

> http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

everything goes well. BUT :

When I arrive to the step Adding Custom Messages(Generating Message Header File) on

> http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Adding%20Custom%20Messages

and try to generate the header file invoking

> rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries My_Package

I'm given : [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named make_library.py below /home/pi/catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_client

Taking a look into ~/catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_client/src I have only the "ros_lib" folder and the "rosserial_client" folder, wich includes "make_library.py and **init**.py", is missing.

Source : https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/tree/hydro-devel/rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client

I don't know if it could be a forgetting updating repo or something. I just wanted to feedback it.

Thanks

EDIT 1 : I have done the next

cp -r ~/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/ /catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_client/src/

Now I can execute rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries My_Package and to get the header file to my new message types.

I just wanted to share this with the community beacuse it seems that during the compiling of rosserial with catkin_make ... make_library.py is missing.

I hope this could help you in the futuro

Thanks for reading

EDIT 2: This solution does not work now. Now if I invoque "rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries My_Package", it seems that it does nothing because it does not create the header.
I don´t know what can we do ..Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119031/rosserial_client-does-not-include-make_library.py/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-13**:
This looks like a bug in rosserial_client and should probably be reported against their bugtracker.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-13**:
Thanks ahendrix for your interest. The problem now is that when I type "rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries My_Package" it´s like nothing happens ... Where can i report this ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-13**:
The issue tracker for rosserial is here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues

**Comment by [luxifu1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/3827/luxifu1989/) on 2014-02-13**:
The same problem that nothing happens in hydro even though I downloaded the newest rosserial_client from the github.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-13**:
I have not reported it yet. I´m reporting when I finished a class . Thanks to both of you.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-14**:
Reported here : https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In groovy/hydro, things were updated so that A) each client has it's own make_libraries.py script (for instance rosserial_adruino is different from rosserial_embedded_linux, this allows us to set things like endianness and whether the platform supports Float64) B) all messages are generated at once for every package on your path. Therefore, you need to run:

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <sketckbook_output_folder>
```

This will generate messages for ALL installed packages. The [Arduino IDE](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) tutorial has been updated, but not the one you reference (I'll update it right now).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luxifu1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/3827/luxifu1989/) on 2014-02-16**:
Thank you for reply. All works well now.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-16**:
I´ve tried 5 minutes ago. It perfectly worked for us. Thanks you so much

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2015-11-20**:
I still can't find it in Fuerte!